Loop which reads not corrupted CSV files to separate dataframes & do not read corrupted files
I am doing course in data science now. I received a task to read csv files from folder and in case these are corrupted do nothing and in case these are fine, save as dataframe).I started with listing files:
   my_dir = getwd()

list_files = list.files(
    path = my_dir ,
    full.names = TRUE,
    pattern = "*.csv"
)

Having list of files I wanted to read only ones not creating errors (I heard about trycatch function), therefore I created loop, which does not work however.
for(i in 1:length(list_files))
  my_data <- tryCatch(lapply(list_files, readcsv), error = function(e) e)  
  }

I only want to read csv's not causing errors into dataframe (name of the dataframe can be identical to file name).
Can you please advise how may I do it?

?try   will take care of this

I think that you are mixing loops and functionnal programming (lapply). You are not using the variable i .
I suggest that you take a second look at classic references (since its seems to be for an homework )

What do you mean by errors?

Simple errors? A syntax like lapply(list(NA, "X", 1, 9), \(i) try(sqrt(i))) might be enough. Fatal errors are different.
